# SSL certificate on NodeJS and express not working

Tags: node.js, express, ssl

I have a NodeJs Application running with express. I have been trying to integrate an SSL certificate but I keep having the same error: `Error: error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line`.

I have tried some solutions I found on stackOverflow like

```
var privateKey = fs.readFileSync( 'privatekey.pem' );
var certificate = fs.readFileSync( 'certificate.pem' );

https.createServer({
    key: privateKey,
    cert: certificate
}, app).listen(port);
```

or

```
var fs = require('fs');
var http = require('http');
var https = require('https');
var privateKey  = fs.readFileSync('privatekey.pem');
var certificate = fs.readFileSync('certificate.pem');
var httpServer = http.createServer(app);
var httpsServer = https.createServer(credentials, app);

httpServer.listen(8081);
httpsServer.listen(8443);
```

But none seem to work. My main problem is that I donwloaded my certificate file from GoDaddy but I only get two `.cert` files. I have read in some websites how to obtain the `.pem` files but I keep getting the same error.

As you can see I am new at using https protocol in NodeJs.

Could you help me solve this problem?

Best regards